Expression to auto-fill field according to the order of polygon creation
I'm working on an urban cartography actualization project, looking for a way to auto-fill a field (let's call it "field_1") in the new polygons created in the buildings layer. I need to complete the field with a number (1) and a letter (A, B, C, etc.) for every new building polygon created inside a plot, according to the order of creation. Also, if the plot has previous building polygons inside, I need to start with the corresponding code (E.g. with two original polygons I should start with 1C). The original layer's "field_1" field is often completed with the wrong code, so I can only rely on the number of polygons to define the starting code for the new ones.
Until now I've been doing this manually, but I'm working with big amounts of information, so automating this would be a great time-saving for me. Additionally, I'm working directly on a database, so I can't create new fields in the process.
I know that there are some tools for this, but the available options don't satisfy what I need:

With "add autoincremental field" it's not possible to use letters
With the plugin "House Numbering" I can do that, but I need to define the starting code for each plot (looking to process more data at a time, and without counting manually each plot's buildings)

I've been working on this, and I've made an expression that counts the number of buildings with the same ID (in the same plot), and traduces this number to the correct letter to start with, adding the number "1" at the beginning:
1||with_variable( 'number', aggregate(
 layer:='Buildings',
 aggregate:='count',
 expression:="id"
 ,filter:="id" = attribute(
@parent, 'id')),char(@number+ 64))

Next, I need to find a way to auto-increase this code for every new polygon made in a plot. I'd prefer to do this with an expression in the field calculator since I've never used PyQGIS, but I don't know if this is even possible. However, I'm open to different alternatives if the field calculator is not an option.
Edit:
This is an example showing two plots with the id and field_1 information from the buildings inside them


Under Layer Properties -> Attributes Form, you should be able to use your expression above (or a small variation of it) as the Default Value for "field_1".
Don't check the Apply default value on update box, as that will recalculate each time, rather than just on creation.

